# Verify Token from Spring Boot App - [OAuth2]

Tags: python, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, oauth

I have a authorization server written in Spring Boot.
I plan on creating a python app which will use the authorization server to validate the token. How can I achieve this in python?

Comment: Try https://pypi.org/project/python-oauth2/

Comment: its not maintained anymore, won't it be deprecated anytime soon?